# Console Minecraft World Tools

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I play minecraft for the ps4 and wanted a few things is there anything out there like mcedit that I can use? If there is where can I download it and how do I use it? One other thing is there any to convert a 360 world to ps4? I know this is a lot of questions I just want to say thanks for all that can help me with this. One other thing is there a limit to how high mobs will spawn of so what is it ?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to install mods on the ps4 version of the game. The PC Version is coded in Java, while the Console Versions are not if I'm not mistaken. Since all mods are written in Java, they were not compatible with the console versions anyways.

Answer (score 0):

There are no mods, no console tools and no world tools.
Console versions of the game are **very closed** in how they work internally, everything is saved on a proprietary and "custom" file system. And the files you export to a USB drive are in an unreadable format, so there's nothing you can do to open them, until someone manages to reverse-engineer the software. Mods are out of question: even if you were able to access the game files, the code is binary and obfuscated so none can understand it and patch it.

**Generally, console edition has nothing to do with Java version: it's not about code being revised, it's about code rewritten from scratch.**